# Rails Render Json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there anything wrong with this?

```
  render :json => { :result => 'success', :profile_pic_path => @user.profile_pic.url(:large) }
```

Do i need to encode or anything like that. I am getting a random error every now and then and I think it has to be that line.

Thanks

Comment: I wish I could. but it's from UPLOADIFY which is via a SWF. the Rails log show know error so I think it's a JSON encoding error

Comment: This isn't alert... nothing happens from the uploadify response:    jsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
   
   alert(jsonObject.profile_pic_path);

Comment: As a shot in the dark, is it possible that `@user.profile_pic` is occasionally `nil`, causing `@user.profile_pic.url(:large)` to throw a nil pointer exception?